# filtering an xmllistcollection using many more TextInputs in flex4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

In my application, I have a spark DataGrid with 9 columns which includes name, ID, Date of joining, DOB, Experience, mobile number, Email and each column have the search field which includes TextField, DateField, NumericStepper to search data. I want to filter the data, based on the user input which means i want to match each field according to the user input's. 
My sample code is:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

        import spark.components.Alert;

        private function xmlListCollectionFilterFun(item:Object):Boolean
        {
            var min:Number = startYear.value;
            var max:Number = endYear.value;
            var exp:Number = item.Experience;
            var bool:Boolean = false;

            if (employeeName.text.length != 0 
                || employeeID.text.length != 0 
                ||designation.text.length != 0
                ||department.text.length != 0
                ||empMobile.text.length != 0
                ||email.text.length != 0
                ||endYear.value != 0
                ||employeeDob.selectedDate
                ||employeeDoj.selectedDate)
            {
                if((item.Name).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeName.text.toLowerCase())  != -1
                    &&(item.Id).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeID.text.toLowerCase()) != -1                      
                    && (item.Designation).toLowerCase().indexOf(designation.text.toLowerCase())!= -1
                    && (item.Department).toLowerCase().indexOf(department.text.toLowerCase()) != -1
                    && (item.Mobile).toLowerCase().indexOf(empMobile.text.toLowerCase()) != -1
                    && (item.Email).toLowerCase().indexOf(email.text.toLowerCase()) != -1
                    && (Date.parse(item.DOB)<=employeeDob.selectedDate.time)
                    && (Date.parse(item.DOJ)<=employeeDoj.selectedDate.time)
                    && (min<=exp && exp<=max))
                {
                    bool = true;
                }

            }
            return bool;

        protected function employeeText_changeHandler():void
        {
            if (employeeName.text.length == 0 && department.text.length == 0 && designation.text.length == 0 && 
                empMobile.text.length == 0 && email.text.length == 0 && endYear.value == 0 && startYear.value == 0 &&
                employeeID.text.length == 0 && !employeeDob.selectedDate && !employeeDoj.selectedDate)
            {
                employeeXMLList.filterFunction = null;
            }
            else
            {
                employeeXMLList.filterFunction = xmlListCollectionFilterFun;
            }
            employeeXMLList.refresh();              

        }

        protected function employeeServiceResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var xmlList:XMLList = XML(event.result).Employee;
            employeeXMLList = new XMLListCollection(xmlList);
        }

        protected function employeeServiceFaultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            spark.components.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString,"Fault Information for POST");
        }

        protected function checkStep():void
        {
            if (startYear.value > endYear.value)
            {
                endYear.value = startYear.value+1;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<fx:Declarations>   
    <s:XMLListCollection id="employeeXMLList" filterFunction="xmlListCollectionFilterFun"/>
    <s:HTTPService id="employeeService" url="http://localhost/demo/TextXmlFile.xml" 
                   method="POST" result="employeeServiceResultHandler(event)"
                   fault="employeeServiceFaultHandler(event)"
                   resultFormat="xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>

    <s:VGroup width="100%">
        <s:HGroup width="100%">
            <s:TextInput id="employeeName" prompt="Employee Name" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="115"/>
            <s:TextInput id="employeeID" prompt="Employee ID" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="95"/>
            <mx:DateField id="employeeDob" yearNavigationEnabled="true" editable="false" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"
                          selectableRange="{{rangeStart:new Date(1970, 01, 01), rangeEnd:new Date()}}"
                          selectedDate="{new Date}"/>
            <s:TextInput id="designation" prompt="Designation" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="195"/>
            <s:TextInput id="department" prompt="Departmant" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="115"/>
            <mx:DateField id="employeeDoj" yearNavigationEnabled="true"  editable="false" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"
                          selectableRange="{{rangeStart:new Date(1970, 01, 01), rangeEnd:new Date()}}"
                          selectedDate="{new Date}"/>
            <s:NumericStepper id="startYear" minimum="0" maximum="50" snapInterval="1" change="checkStep(),employeeText_changeHandler()"/>
            <s:NumericStepper id="endYear" minimum="1" maximum="50" snapInterval="1"
                              change="employeeText_changeHandler()" value="20"/>
            <s:TextInput id="empMobile" prompt="Mobile Number" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="170"/>
            <s:TextInput id="email" prompt="Email ID" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="310"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup height="100%" width="100%">
        <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{employeeXMLList}" width="100%" height="500">
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayCollection>
                    <s:GridColumn id="nameCol" dataField="Name" headerText="Name:" width="120"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="idCol" dataField="Id" headerText="ID:" width="100"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="dobCol" dataField="DOB" headerText="DOB:" width="100"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="designationCol" dataField="Designation" headerText="Designation:" width="200"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="departmentCol" dataField="Department" headerText="Department:" width="120"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="dojCol" dataField="DOJ" headerText="DOJ:" width="100"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="experienceCol" dataField="Experience" headerText="Experience:" width="100"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="mobileCol" dataField="Mobile" headerText="Mobile:" width="200"/>
                    <s:GridColumn id="emailCol" dataField="Email" headerText="Email:" width="300"/>
                </s:ArrayCollection>
            </s:columns>
        </s:DataGrid>
            </s:HGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
```

My Questions are:

1. I want the remove the selectedDate property from the DateField which means when the data is loaded on DataGrid all the filter fields should be empty.
2. I am using single if condition for filter. How can I split it?
3. I want to filter the data even some of the filter filed is empty.

**EDIT**

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

        import spark.components.Alert;

        private function xmlListCollectionFilterFun(item:Object):Boolean
        {
            if (employeeName.text.length != 0)
            {
                var xmlName:String = (item.Name).toLowerCase();
                var textName:String = employeeName.text.toLowerCase();
                if((item.Name).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeName.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (employeeID.text.length != 0)
            {
                if ((item.Id).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeID.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                } 
            }
            if (employeeDob.selectedDate)
            {
                var dob:String = item.DOB;
                var dobDate:Date = new Date();
                var matches:Array = dob.split("/");
                dobDate.setUTCFullYear(int(matches[0]), int(matches[1]) - 1, int(matches[2]))
                if (ObjectUtil.dateCompare(employeeDob.selectedDate,dobDate) == -1)
                {
                    return true;        
                }
            } 
            if (designation.text.length != 0)
            {
                if ((item.Designation).toLowerCase().indexOf(designation.text.toLowerCase())!= -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (department.text.length != 0)
            {
                if ((item.Department).toLowerCase().indexOf(department.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (employeeDoj.selectedDate)
            {
                var doj:String = item.DOJ;
                var dojDate:Date = new Date();
                var matche:Array = doj.split("/");
                dojDate.setUTCFullYear(int(matche[0]), int(matche[1]) - 1, int(matche[2]))
                if (ObjectUtil.dateCompare(employeeDoj.selectedDate,dojDate) == -1)
                {
                    return true;        
                }
            } 
            if (endYear.value != 0)
            {
                var min:Number = startYear.value;
                var max:Number = endYear.value;
                var exp:Number = item.Experience;
                if ((min<=exp) && (exp<=max))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            } 
            if (empMobile.text.length != 0)
            {
                if ((item.Mobile).toLowerCase().indexOf(empMobile.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            } 
            if (email.text.length != 0)
            {
                if ((item.Email).toLowerCase().indexOf(email.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected function employeeText_changeHandler():void
        {
            if (employeeName.text.length == 0 && department.text.length == 0 && designation.text.length == 0 && 
                empMobile.text.length == 0 && email.text.length == 0 && endYear.value == 0 && startYear.value == 0 &&
                employeeID.text.length == 0 && !employeeDob.selectedDate && !employeeDoj.selectedDate)
            {
                employeeXMLList.filterFunction = null;
            }
            else
            {
                employeeXMLList.filterFunction = xmlListCollectionFilterFun;
            }
            employeeXMLList.refresh();              

        }

        protected function employeeService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var xmlList:XMLList = XML(event.result).Employee;
            employeeXMLList = new XMLListCollection(xmlList);
        }

        protected function employeeService_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            spark.components.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString,"Fault Information for POST");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<fx:Declarations>   
    <s:XMLListCollection id="employeeXMLList" filterFunction="xmlListCollectionFilterFun"/>
    <s:HTTPService id="employeeService" url="http://localhost/demo/TextXmlFile.xml" 
                   method="POST" result="employeeService_resultHandler(event)"
                   fault="employeeService_faultHandler(event)"
                   resultFormat="xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="30"/>
</s:layout>
<mx:VBox width="100%">
    <s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Label id="mainLabel" text="Employee Details"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:TextInput id="employeeName" prompt="Employee Name" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="115"/>
        <s:TextInput id="employeeID" prompt="Employee ID" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="95"/>
        <mx:DateField id="employeeDob" yearNavigationEnabled="true" editable="true" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"
                      selectableRange="{{rangeStart:new Date(1970, 01, 01), rangeEnd:new Date()}}"/>
        <s:TextInput id="designation" prompt="Designation" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="195"/>
        <s:TextInput id="department" prompt="Departmant" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="115"/>
        <mx:DateField id="employeeDoj" yearNavigationEnabled="true"  editable="true" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"
                      selectableRange="{{rangeStart:new Date(1970, 01, 01), rangeEnd:new Date()}}"/>
        <s:NumericStepper id="startYear" minimum="0" maximum="50" snapInterval="1" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"/>
        <s:NumericStepper id="endYear" minimum="0" maximum="50" snapInterval="1" change="employeeText_changeHandler()"/>
        <s:TextInput id="empMobile" prompt="Mobile Number" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="170"/>
        <s:TextInput id="email" prompt="Email ID" change="employeeText_changeHandler()" width="310"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" dataProvider="{employeeXMLList}" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayCollection>
                <s:GridColumn id="nameCol" dataField="Name" headerText="Name:" width="120"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="idCol" dataField="Id" headerText="ID:" width="100"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="dobCol" dataField="DOB" headerText="DOB:" width="100"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="designationCol" dataField="Designation" headerText="Designation:" width="200"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="departmentCol" dataField="Department" headerText="Department:" width="120"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="dojCol" dataField="DOJ" headerText="DOJ:" width="100"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="experienceCol" dataField="Experience" headerText="Experience:" width="100"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="mobileCol" dataField="Mobile" headerText="Mobile:" width="200"/>
                <s:GridColumn id="emailCol" dataField="Email" headerText="Email:" width="300"/>
            </s:ArrayCollection>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</mx:VBox>
```

Here I done everything. But filter performs like employeeName.Text || employeeId.text ||..... But i need filter like  employeeName.Text && employeeId.text &&.....

My current output is:
[image]

But I want like this:
[image]

**Update**

```
                var bool:Boolean = true;
            if (employeeName.text.length != 0)
            {
                if((item.Name).toLowerCase().indexOf(employeeName.text.toLowerCase()) != -1) 

                {
                    bool = bool && true;
                }
                else
                {
                    bool = bool && false;
                }
            }
```

It might correct.

Answer (score 0):

About spiting it you can make a small filter function for each column and combine them

```
function nameFilter
function emailFilter

function collectionFilter(iterm:*):Boolean{
 return nameFilter(item)&&emailFilter(item)&&....
}
```

With this approach you can implement them one by one and test the filtering.

If a filter field is empty then you just return true from your filter

```
function nameFilter(item:*):Boolean{
 var name:String=item.name;
 var filter:String=employeeName.text;
 if(!filter||filter.length==0) return true;
 return name.indexOf(filter)==0;//change this to get your results
//you may want to make the name and filter lowercase before this
}
```

So the idea is to split that large function in smaller ones, a function should be doing one thing and be simple, I also try to make them without side effects if possible(to compute and return a result and not change any fields). You may ignore this rule sometimes  but this is has many advantages especially the fact that is easy to read and reason about.

EDIT
This is wrong

```
    if (empMobile.text.length != 0)
    {
        if ((item.Mobile).toLowerCase().indexOf(empMobile.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

becausethe code will not reach the other checks under so this is one place where you will wrong results, you could do it by negating that and returning false because if you want AND (that all filters must pass) then you can return false when you find the first filter that fails

Comment: @user I think your error is that after you check t if the name fits then you return true and the other checks are not done(because return will exit the function) I think you also have an error where you init bool to false then you check if you have at least one filter and applyu the filter but if not you return false (maybe is not an error but it looks like that it should return true if no filters are set). Do you know to step trough code with the debugger? this will help you

Comment: sorry. I already tried to find my mistake through the debugger. But I couldn't find my mistake.

Comment: anything else or any other tip?

Comment: @user now you have a large function that is broken, split it in smaller functions as I said then you check each small function in part to see where the problem is. Also I would start by adding a breakpoint and check in debugger step by step what is happening, so as in your images I would skip the filtering for John then at second time the filter is called for the second name that is not john I expect it to return false so I watch in debugger step by step and see where it return true , then fix that and do it again

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am trying to split my code as a smaller functions.

Comment: Yes.... I get your point. I have to use false when the condition is fails and I have to combine the next next results even  it's failing or success.

Comment: @user only on succes because your first tests may be success but if the last one fails you have to fail and now in the code if first one succeeds your test succeeds and is wrong, for fail if your first test fails then you can skip checking all the others because you already know that it will fail because the first one failed